# kendo ui datepicker k-on-change is not working.

Tags: kendo-ui

I have the following code

```
<input kendo-date-picker k-options="vm.monthSelectorOptions" k-format="'MMMM yyyy'" k-ng-model="myController.selectedMonth" k-on-change="alert('test')" />
```

When I change the date selected the alert is not been executed.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute context is on scope there. You need to have an alert method defined on the scope. So it won't works as you expected. But you can define your change method on the k-options scope variable.

```
<input kendo-date-picker k-options="vm.monthSelectorOptions" k-format="'MMMM yyyy'" k-ng-model="myController.selectedMonth"/>
```

(k-on-change is removed because it'll override the one in monthSelectorOptions)

and in controller:

```
vm.monthSelectorOptions = {
   change:function(){
    alert("Test");
   }
   ...other options
}
```

Or you can define the corresponding method on your scope if you want to use k-on-change.

```
<input kendo-date-picker k-options="vm.monthSelectorOptions" k-format="'MMMM yyyy'" k-ng-model="myController.selectedMonth" k-on-change="vm.alert('test')" />
```

and in your controller

```
 vm.alert = function(str){
   alert(str);
 };
```